# unbind an angular element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code inside of a directive and I want to make sure it gets cleaned up when the scope is destroyed. I've looked online as well as the code and I was wondering how do I unbind an element.

```
var window = angular.element($window);
window.bind("resize", function(e){
    abc();
});
```

**Solution:**

```
var abc = function() {};

var window = angular.element($window);
window.bind('resize', abc);

scope.$on('$destroy', function(e) {
    window.unbind('resize', abc);
});
```

Comment: Is unbind no working for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unbind the function from `window` when the directive's scope gets destroyed. Hence in your directive, you'll invoke a clean up function on the scope's destroy's event:

`$scope.$on('$destroy', cleanUp);`

Create a `cleanUp` function and call the jQuery's [unbind function](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

There is an example in [this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031381/how-to-safely-clean-up-angularjs-event-binding-in-a-directive), but with the [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function instead (which seems similar to `unbind`, but unavailable in jqLite). Also per this SO entry, you might have to name your function as you'll need to reference it again as a parameter in the `unbind` call.

Comment: `off` and `on` functions are not available in [`jqLite`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). They're in the full jQuery version. `bind` and `unbind` are in `jqLite`.

Comment: Ah thanks for the correction, good to know! I've never observed as I use the full jQuery version with Angular.

Comment: so I just need to call bind and unbind then.. thanks I'll give this an attempt.

Comment: I think I got it, I just hope the unbind is unbinding the handler :)

Comment: I updated my question with my solution that I hope is unwiring abc :D

Comment: Ok that should do it! To check if the unbind is called, you can always profile the application with the Chrome profiler or put a temporary console logging. On the topic of leaks, there is an interesting "3 snapshopts" technique to discover potential leaks [explained here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wUVmf78gG-ra5aOxvTfYdiLkdGaR9OhXRnOlIcEmu2s/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000#slide=id.g322f9af_2_22).