# Custom directive not working if i change the name of the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I tried to implement a window resize custom directive and it works fine.

The problem is it works only if i use the directive name as resize.
Otherwise if i use different name as windowsize,it is triggered only at the time of page refresh.

here is the  controller code

```
  var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function AppController($scope) {
    /* Logic goes here */
}

> > app.directive('windowsize', function($window){
>         return function(scope,element){
>             var w=angular.element($window);
>             scope.getWindowDimension=function(){
>                 return{
>                      'w': w.width()
>                 };
>             };
>              scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimension, function (newValue, oldValue) {
>              scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
>              console.log( scope.windowWidth);
> 
>         }, true);
>               w.bind('windowsize', function () {
>             scope.$apply();
>         });
>        };
>      })



html code
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="AppController"  windowsize>
    window.height: {{windowHeight}}
    <br />window.width: {{windowWidth}}
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors your getting before refreshing?

Comment: You should try w.bind('resize') rather then w.bind('windowsize')

Comment: I am not getting any error. If i replace directive name windowsize to resize it works fine. @SaEChowdary

Comment: why cant i use windowsize instead of resize @Ashish panchal

Comment: @SanjayHp : you are binding an event and I suppose there is no such event like windowsize that's why. hope it will work for you.

Comment: Ok but can i tried using directiveName as windowSize  and  w.bind('resize'). It is not working. @AshishPanchal

Comment: any error you are getting ? refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622673/angularjs-watch-window-resize-inside-directive this link hope it will help you. @SanjayHp

Comment: @AshishPanchal thanks for the help i got it

Comment: welcome @SanjayHp great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function AppController($scope) {
    /* Logic goes here */
}

 app.directive('windowsize', function($window){
         return function(scope,element){
             var w=angular.element($window);
             scope.getWindowDimension=function(){
                 return{
                      'w': w.width()
                 };
             };
              scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimension, function (newValue, oldValue) {
              scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
              console.log( scope.windowWidth); 
         }, true);
               w.bind('resize', function () {
             scope.$apply();
         });
        };
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
html code
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="AppController"  windowsize>
    window.height: {{windowHeight}}
    <br />window.width: {{windowWidth}}
    <br />
</div>
```

Here In this example you done everything correct but one small mistake, you bind event windowresize is not event so use resize and try it(I just correct for width only)